# T SQL calculate 2 fields from temp tables with NULL value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I've got 2 temp tables in my query and I'm trying to add up 2 of the fields.  The problem is sometimes the 2nd temp table results to a 'NULL' value and then when I add up the 2 fields I get a 'NULL' Value:

```
#1 :  100
#2 :  NULL

select 
@tm as tm
,'Sales' = (a.Sales + b.Sales)
from #1 a
left join #2 b
on a.tm = b.tm
```

Result:

```
tm  Sales
12  NULL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `COALESCE`, one value might be null,

```
select  @tm as tm,
       'Sales' = (COALESCE(a.Sales, 0) + COALESCE(b.Sales,0))
from   #1 a
       left join #2 b on a.tm = b.tm
```